# Mobile application Load testing

Tags: mobile, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I want to do the load and performance testing for mobile app like wtapp,facebook separate apk. so is there any method to do the load testing using jmeter.

As I have seen jmeter proxy setup in mobile application but there are recording mobile web application. I want test the separate application not browser dependent.

I want to record the separate apk for example.. i will open wtapp and login into wtapp those API calls should be recorded in jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

For which operating system?

- iOS - it's sufficient to [install JMeter's certificate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and [enable full trust for it](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477)
- Android - you will need access to application source code in order to be able to amend its [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) like it's described in [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording) article. If you don't have access you will need to use rooted device/emulator and [install JMeter's certificate into your root CA storage](https://help.ivanti.com/ap/help/en_US/fd/2021/Content/FileDirector/Admin/Clients/Install_Root_Certificate_on_Android.htm)